# Thunderbird suddenly became my default email client

Tags: thunderbird, email, google

When I had Ubuntu 11.10  I had the Google email client and was happy with it.  Now, with 12.04,  I have suddenly found that Thunderbird has become default and I don't like it.  Why did it suddenly get shoved off on me and how do I get rid of it?  I liked Google email client!
Thanks for any help,

Hubert Hickey

Answer (score 1):

you can change the default email client on Ubuntu using the **System Settings**, just click on the **Details**

[image]

and click on the **Default Applications** tab (red arrow).

[image]

there will be a selectbox (blue arrow) which allows you to change the default E-Mail application your system.

Now I don't really know what you mean with Google E-Mail client, but i guess you mean Gmails web interface, in this case just select Chrome/Chromium Browser and it should work.